# Consequences of tubular neighbourhood theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider an oriented manifold without boundary S embedded in an oriented manifold M.
The tubular neighbourhood theorem says that there is a neighbourhood T of S in M which is diffeomorphic to $N_{S|M}$. Moreover the 0 section of $N_{S|M}$ composed with this diffeomormphism is the inclusion map $i \colon S \to T \subset M$. ($N_{S|M}$ is the quotient of $(TM)_{|S}$ by $TS$).

I have read on my notes that we can see every form $\omega$ on $N_{S|M}$ as a cohomolgy class on T. If $\omega$ has compact support on the vertical direction, then it vanish near the boundary of $\partial T$(closure if T), so we can extend it to a form on M...

My question is: how the form $\omega$ vanish near $\partial T$??

Comment: In general the form $w$ does not vanishes on near the boundary. But if you multiply fiberwise a bump function to $w$, then one can make it vanish along the fiber. You may want to take a look of the book "Differential forms in algebraic topology" by Bott and Tu. These construction is quite important from the topological point of view.

Comment: @John I have read the chapter in Bott-Tu (pag. 66) that treat this. But it doesn't explain my doubt. He only says that "the form (extension on all M) is defined because we are only concerned with forms on the tubular neighbourhood T which vanish near the boundary of T"

Comment: The identication $N_{S|M}$ to $T$ is more or less like identifying every normal fibers $N_x$ at a point to a unit ball $B \subset N_x$. if $w$ has compact support on each fibers, then correspondingly it vanishes on $\partial B$. While $\partial T$ is like $S \times \partial B$ (More precisely a sphere bundle over $S$). Thus $w$ vanishes on $\partial T$.

Comment: @John Thanks you very much.